# How to create page slider with page number indicator instead of dot indicator in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-packages, flutter-design

I want to create a page slider like shown in image but can't figure out how? All the methods I found was related to dot indicator. How to create this?

[page slider with page number indicator instead of dot indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m42qo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out: [Carousel slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)
You can provide a custom widget as the slider and there are several accompanying examples there. If you need any more help with it, please do let me know.